# Titulo de encabezado en dbms_output.put_line()

Tags: oracle

Estoy ejecutando el siguiente procedimiento

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE mayorventas1
IS
CURSOR cventas
IS
SELECT 
nombre AS producto,
fventas(idproductos) AS ventas ,
fmejorcliente(idproductos) AS mejorCliente
FROM productos ORDER BY ventas desc;
lista cventas%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN 
    FOR lista IN cventas LOOP
         dbms_output.put_line(lista.producto||'  '||lista.ventas||'  '||lista.mejorCliente);
    END LOOP;   
END;
```

Cuando realizo el `execute` me arroja la siguiente información.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quisiera saber si hay forma de colocar títulos de encabezado a cada una de las columnas que me arroja el dbms_output.put_line()

Answer (score 1):

En lugar de usar el carácter " "(espacio) que lo que hace es separarte del final de la anterior palabra solamente un espacio y no se alinean, usa mejor chr(9), tal que:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE mayorventas1
IS
CURSOR cventas
IS
SELECT 
nombre AS producto,
fventas(idproductos) AS ventas ,
fmejorcliente(idproductos) AS mejorCliente
FROM productos ORDER BY ventas desc;
lista cventas%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN 
    FOR lista IN cventas LOOP
         dbms_output.put_line(lista.producto||chr(9)||lista.ventas||chr(9)||lista.mejorCliente);
    END LOOP;

END;
```